# PHP7 compile from source - got several test failures

Tags: php, php-7

I'm trying to compile php 7.1.12 from source on Ubuntu server 16.04. All looks good until `make test` completed. I got several test failures. I also tried compiling php 7.1.11, 7.1.7, 5.6.23 from source (I also tried on Debian 9). They all have test failures. Does it matter?

```
=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Bug #64267 (CURLOPT_INFILE doesn't allow reset) [ext/curl/tests/bug64267.phpt]
Bug #71523 (Copied handle with new option CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER crashes while curl_multi_exec) [ext/curl/tests/bug71523.phpt]
Test function getservbyname() by substituting argument 2 with emptyUnsetUndefNull values. [ext/standard/tests/general_functions/getservbyname_variation10.phpt]
Test function getservbyname() by substituting argument 2 with boolean values. [ext/standard/tests/general_functions/getservbyname_variation9.phpt]
FPM: Startup and connect [sapi/fpm/tests/002.phpt]
FPM: Test Unix Domain Socket [sapi/fpm/tests/009.phpt]
FPM: Test IPv4 all addresses (bug #68420) [sapi/fpm/tests/011.phpt]
FPM: Test reload configuration (bug #68442) [sapi/fpm/tests/012.phpt]
FPM: Test for log_level in fpm_unix_init_main #68381 [sapi/fpm/tests/013.phpt]
FPM: Test for pm.start_servers default calculation message being a notice and not a warning #68458 [sapi/fpm/tests/014.phpt]
FPM: Test fastcgi_finish_request function [sapi/fpm/tests/017.phpt]
FPM: Test global prefix [sapi/fpm/tests/019.phpt]
FPM: Test pool prefix [sapi/fpm/tests/020.phpt]
FPM: HTTP_PROXY - CVE-2016-5385 [sapi/fpm/tests/022-cve-2016-5385.phpt]
=====================================================================
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to run `make test` for PHP to successfully compile.

Comment: Do they represent your usage cases?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil Yea, it can compile. I'm wondering if they are known issues or because test environment requirements are not met. Is it common to get test failures when compiling php from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about test failures, if your compilation job finished successfully then the resulting PHP should work.  You should be prompted to send a report of the failed tests to the PHP project - please do so, it helps understand if these failures are actual errors.

Comment: Have you ever got test failures? I didn't compile php from source before.

Comment: Yes, it's not terribly unusual to see a few.  If your compilation succeeds but you see some test failures, your compiled PHP will work.  By sending the test results to the PHP project when prompted, you help them understand which tests fail on a system like your.s.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set environment variable: `TEST_FPM_RUN_AS_ROOT=1`